# iPhone keeps asking for iCloud password (almost everyday)

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I've seen a few similar posts, but they are quite old, and the problem I have is not exactly the same, so here it is:

For a few months (and probably after I upgraded to iOS 11, although I don't remember exactly), my iPhone has kept asking for my iCloud password in the settings.

Nothing is blocked, if I don't enter my password I can still use the phone and all the services normally. However, it displays a notification and a red dot on the settings icon, and this bothers me. When I enter my password, the notification disappears, and it comes back after some time (a few hours, one day, three days...).

Here are a few screenshots of the "workflow" (sorry for the French on the screen):

1. Notification on the lock screen. It says:

> **Update of Apple ID:** some services related to your account will only be available once you are reconnected.

[image]

2. Notification in the settings, in the iCloud block

[image]

3. Message when I click on the notification. It says:

> **Update of Apple ID:** some services related to your account will only be available once you are reconnected.

[image]

4. Asks for my iCloud password:

[image]

When I reconnect, I'm redirected to the settings, with no confirmation message, and the notification disappears. And then, a few hours/days later, the loop starts again...

My iPhone is an SE running the last iOS (11.2.1). I've already tried to log out from iCloud and log back in, but it didn't solve the problem. Also, it's not a used iPhone asking for an old iCloud account. Any tips on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using any apps that you obtained from a Family account or are using by signing-in to the Apple ID of someone else?

Comment: My main iCloud account is French, and I have two apps that I downloaded with my Spanish iCloud account that I used when I was in Spain. Sometimes in the AppStore I was asked for the Spanish account password (this used to happen in iOS 10 when updates were available for these two apps, but since iOS 11 they update without asking for the password), but in the iPhone settings it's always the password of my main account which is asked. And otherwise, I don't have a family account, I don't have apps installed with a friend's Apple ID.

Comment: Same problem. I suggest you to call Apple Care for this since it looks like a software problem introduced with iOS 11 and most notably identified by users who never used iCloud.